Why does the install prompt on my PWA doesn't show on some devices?
I have a newly-deployed PWA and want to test it in the browser. However, on some devices the install action doesn't appear in the context value, but on other devices it appear.
The screenshots below are from two different Android phones, both running the latest version of the OS and Chrome.


How can I make sure that my app can be installed on all mobile devices running the latest version of browsers?
Update: the add to home screen button on the failing device actually tells you to install the app. Therefore I believe it to be a browser bug.
